# how to loop through array items multiple times

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

So, if I wanted to log the numbers one to five once, I might write something like:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]

function loop(n) {
  for (var i=0;i<n;i++) {
    console.log(array[i])
  }
}

loop(5)
```

but how would I log the numbers one to five more than once?

eg writing loop(10); to get the following result:
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
4
5

Obviously at the moment I get 'undefined' for anything above loop(5)

Answer (score 22):

Use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) :

```
function loop(n) {
  for (var i=0;i<n;i++) {
    console.log(array[i%array.length])
  }
}
```